# How do I include Responder in ActionController::Metal in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

I'm working a Rails 3 controller that has a very specific, limited purpose, and all I need is for it to respond_to :json.

This screencast says my controller can inherit from ActionController::Metal, and then just include the functionality I need to make things faster:
http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3/action-controller

When my controller looks like this:

```
class FoldersController < ActionController::Metal
  respond_to :json
  def all
    respond_with Folder.all
  end
end
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `respond_to' for FoldersController:Class
```

I've tried including Responder, ActionController::Responder, ActionController::Metal::Responder, but none of them work. What do I include to get this responder functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include more classes, not only Responder. Here is my ApplicationController, but not all includes you may need:

```
class Api::ApplicationController < ActionController::Metal
  include ActionController::Helpers
  include ActionController::UrlFor

  include ActionController::Redirecting
  include ActionController::Rendering           # enables rendering
  include ActionController::ConditionalGet      # required for respond_to and respond_with
  include ActionController::MimeResponds        # enables serving different content types like :xml or :json

  include ActionController::Cookies             # enables cookies
  include AbstractController::Callbacks         # callbacks for your authentication logic
  include ActiveSupport::Rescuable              # enables resque_from

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Answer (score -1):

[ActionController::MimeResponds](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) looks to be the path.